# How to merge 2 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, insert

I would like merge 2 MySQL tables without adding the same lines.
I have 2 tables with the sames columns but not the same row, such as.

```
table_1
+-------+--------+------+
| Name  | ResNum | Code | 
+-------+--------+------+
| User1 | 25BAM8 | PAR1 |
| User2 | E26J09 | COP3 |
+-------+--------+------+

table_2
+-------+--------+------+
| Name  | ResNum | Code | 
+-------+--------+------+
| User1 | 25BAM8 | PAR1 |
| User3 | 34VNS2 | PAR1 |
| User4 | EZQVG5 | COP3 |
+-------+--------+------+
```

I want when merging table_2 to table_1, got this:

```
table_1
+-------+--------+------+
| Name  | ResNum | Code | 
+-------+--------+------+
| User1 | 25BAM8 | PAR1 |
| User2 | E26J09 | COP3 |
| User3 | 34VNS2 | PAR1 |
| User4 | EZQVG5 | COP3 |
+-------+--------+------+
```

I have already tried with INSERT IGNORE INTO and REPLACE INTO command but it copy the existing rows, like that:

```
table_1
+-------+--------+------+
| Name  | ResNum | Code | 
+-------+--------+------+
| User1 | 25BAM8 | PAR1 |
| User1 | 25BAM8 | PAR1 |
| User2 | E26J09 | COP3 |
| User3 | 34VNS2 | PAR1 |
| User4 | EZQVG5 | COP3 |
+-------+--------+------+
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution would be to put a temporary UNIQUE index on Name on table_1:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_name ON table_1(Name)
```

To transfer the actual rows, use a SELECT INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(Name, ResNum, Code) SELECT Name, ResNum, Code FROM table_2.
```

Then drop the UNIQUE index:

```
DROP INDEX unique_name ON table_1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a UNIQUE key, if uniqueness in those fields is important to you.

Then you can do an `INSERT ... SELECT` without problem, and you won't run into issues with this in the future.

Comment: Thank you.If I want to set as "UNIQUE Key" the column "ResNum". How should I do? Should I do it at the table creation or I can do it now?

Answer (score 1):

The below query should work fine.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 T1,TABLE_2 T2
WHERE T1.NAME = T2.NAME
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 T1, TABLE_2 T2
WHERE T1.NAME != T2.NAME
```